# VBS / Making Word Document Visible

Tags: vbscript, ms-word

I have a simple script that I would like to run and it check to see if there's a word document open, and if it's open, then make it visible. It can be ANY word document, so I can't make it specifically to any file name.

Here's the code so far:

```
Dim Word

Set Word = GetObject(, "Word.Application")

If Word Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Is not running"
Else
    MsgBox "Is running"
    Word.Visible = True
End If
```

Everything works except for `Word.Visible = True`. The popup shows "Is running" but the word document isn't brought to the front, selected or made visible at all. What am I missing? Thanks!

Updated details:

I've even tried it like this...

```
Dim Word
Set Word = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
Word.Visible = True
Word.Selection.TypeText "Hello Word"
```

With this code...As long as Word is currently opened, it should make it visible, then write Hello Word. It does write Hello Word, but doesn't make it visible. One I run it, I can see Word flashing in my task bar because Hello Word was added, but still doesn't make it visible. Hope that helps!

Comment: Is `MsgBox` really necessary to show before `Word.Visible`? If you interchange those two lines, Word should be visible.

Comment: I've tried switching the order just to be sure but it's still doesn't show. Only reason the MsgBox is there now is because I wanted to make sure it was properly checking it if was running or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you're misunderstanding how the `Visible` property works. That property defines if the application is visible at all or not (as in "does or doesn't show up in the taskbar").

Apparently your application already is visible (otherwise you wouldn't be able to see it flashing in the taskbar), but what you actually want is to un-minimize it and bring it to the front. The [`WindowState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa224328%28v=office.11%29.aspx) property should do that for you:

```
Const wdWindowStateNormal   = 0
Const wdWindowStateMaximize = 1
Const wdWindowStateMinimize = 2

Set wd = GetObject(, "Word.Application")

If wd Is Nothing Then
  MsgBox "Is not running"
Else
  MsgBox "Is running"
  wd.WindowState = wdWindowStateNormal
End If
```

Comment: Thank you so much...Now that you put it that way, I did have a misunderstanding of the Visible property! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

```
Set oWord = CreateObject ("Word.Application")

oWord.Visible = True
```

Comment: I know that doing it this way does make Word visible...but this creates a new session of Word, I want to have it check and see if there is one already open, and if so, make that one visible. If there isn't one open then I do not want a new one.